# java noob: error:cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

So i wrote a simple code

```
int k=3;
if (k==3)
{ int a[i][j]=new int[10][10];  }
a[2][3]= 4;
System.out.println(a[2][3]);
```

I am getting an error in atom editor that cannot find symbol , 
I want my array to be initialized in if statement

Comment: where is `atom` define ?

Comment: Atom editor i am using

Comment: What if `k != 3`?

Comment: Actually i am using a code in which if my certain variable (Lets say k) is equal to 1 then i want to declare (a[]) as a 1d array and if k=3 then declare (a[][]) as a 2 d array. So after the initialization of array is done , later in my code i want to use the array a . Hence it is mandatory for me to declare a in if statement depending on the value of k

Comment: How are you planning on using the array if you don't know its dimensions?

Comment: I have variables which are entered by user to make my dimensions, but the 2-d or 3-d will depend on the value of k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[][]=new int[10][10]; // the bounds are taken care by the new declaration
```

> I want my array to be initialized in if statement

Also if you put it under `if`, that would be local to the `if`. Hence what would work for you is:

```
if (k==3) { 
    int a[][]=new int[10][10]; 
    a[2][3]= 4;
    System.out.println(a[2][3]);
}
```

---

A better practice to declare an array that can be used not just locally would be somewhat like -

```
int a[][]=new int[10][10]; 
if (k==3) { 
    a[2][3]= 4;
}
System.out.println(a[2][3]);
```

Comment: Actually i am using a code in which if my certain variable (Lets say k) is equal to 1 then i want to declare (a[]) as a 1d array and if k=3 then declare (a[][]) as a 2 d array. So after the initialization of array is done , later in my code i want to use the array a . Hence it is mandatory for me to declare a in if statement depending on the value of k

Comment: @Coder Well I am sure there is a dupe for that type of creation in SO, just couldn't find one at this point of time. You might though want to rethink your design of creating multi dimensional arrays based on a certain input.